# PHP preg_match and multiple lines until empty line

Tags: php, preg-match, string

I want to get text from email via php preg_march, my text looks like:

```
Details: Cras ultrices quam id nisl

Additional Informations
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nunc eu enim non ipsum feugiat aliquam. Cras eget orci tellus, ac feugiat ligula.
Proin tristique lobortis lacinia. Morbi facilisis

Next line with value: Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

I want to get all below "Additional Informations" until empty line.

Comment: '/^Additional Informations(.*)[\n](.*)$/mi' but it's not good for me because sometimes after "Additional Informations" are two lines, sometimes more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'~Additional Informations\\r?\\n(.+?)\\r?\\n\\r?\\n~si'
```

Try this one.

It does work:

```
$string = <<<SZ
Details: Cras ultrices quam id nisl

Additional Informations
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nunc eu enim non ipsum feugiat aliquam. Cras eget orci tellus, ac feugiat ligula.
Proin tristique lobortis lacinia. Morbi facilisis

Next line with value: Lorem ipsum dolor sit
SZ;
preg_match('~Additional Informations\\r?\\n(.+?)\\r?\\n\\r?\\n~si', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```